# How to get a div to stay the same size

Tags: html, css

Hi all im a newb and trying to get my head round CSS. I have create a div which holds a login and password form for my site. When the user successfully logs in this form disappears using PHP and a welcome message appears to greet the user. My problem is that because the message is smaller than the login form the div shrinks to that size and does not stay the same.

I have tried playing around with width, height, using various position commands like absolute but with no luck.

This is my css for the div called infobox:

```
    #infobox {

border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding-left:16px; 
padding-top:10px;
background:#dddddd;
width:237px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
float: right; 
padding-bottom: 10px;

    }
```

And this is my header css where the above is nested in (if this helps)

```
    #header {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0;
position: relative;
margin-top: -36px;
    }
```

Kind regards

Comment: Set the `height` of `#infobox`.

Comment: hi `wrap` your `#infobox` with `relative` position and make the `#infobox` `absolute` position it easy to manipulate absolute position if you `wrap` it with `relative`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set `width:500px;` and `height:300px;` (or whatever size you want) the div should stay the same size. Also, you can set `overflow:hidden;` so that if whatever is in the div goes beyond those bounds, it is not shown, and does not resize the div.

Comment: Thank you I feel like a dummy now, much appreciated tho - Andy

Comment: No problem. I just started in css a few weeks ago. You're about to learn a lot of things super fast. It's a very powerful framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Maybe it will help you out.

```
enter code here


#infobox {
width:400px;
height:250px;
border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding-left:16px; 
padding-top:10px;
background:#dddddd;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
float: right; 
padding-bottom: 10px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```